# If two batteries that are fully charged with opposite polarities and one has higher emf.Does one will charge the other?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]if there are two batteries fully charged  in a circuit connected in series and one has higher emf than the other does one charge the other or not ? does any current pass in the circuit ?and if yes explain how the current will move exactly

Comment: What else is in the circuit? Or is it just the 2 batteries connected end to end? The current will be determined by the resistance of the circuit and batteries, and the total emf. You question does not make clear how the batteries are connected. Try to attach a drawing of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

If the two batteries are parallel connected, the battery with the higher emf will discharge while the battery with the lower emf will *overcharge* (I say this because you stipulate that both batteries are initially *fully* charged).  The electric current will be out of the positive terminal of the higher emf battery and into the positive terminal of the lower emf battery.

Depending on the batteries used, the current could be high enough to destroy (by e.g., fire, explosion) one or both batteries.

If the two batteries are anti-parallel connected, *both* batteries will discharge.  For both batteries, the electric current will be out of the positive terminal.  As before, the current could be destructive.

Answer (score 1):

If the batteries are just connected together, then a current will flow, determined by the sum of the internal resistances of the batteries and the voltage resulting from connecting the batteries. If the same poles of both batteries are connected (+ to +, - to -) then the resultant voltage is the difference between the tow batteries. If the batteries are connected + to -, then the resultant voltage is the sum of the two.

Either way, the resultant current will likely destroy both batteries, as batteries have very low internal resistant, hence the current will be high.

If that does not answer your question, please provide more details about your circuit.

EDIT

From your circuit, the batteries oppose each other, and the resistance in the circuit is $R_1 + R_{i1} + R_{i2}$, where the $R_i$'s are the internal resistances of the batteries. Hence the total current is: $$I=\frac{(V_{B1}-V_{B2})}{R_1 + R_{i1} + R_{i2}}$$

If $V_{B1}>V_{B2}$ then the current will flow from the positive terminal of battery 1 to the positive terminal of battery 2. Note this is the "conventional" current. The actual electron flow is the opposite, as electrons have negative charge

Comment: i add an image so you can see it